# Reading from a json file

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to read from a json file and get only the phone numbers back i am using java and using the library org.json.simple and i am getting a error that says

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at Heatmap.main(Heatmap.java:21)"

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Heatmap {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\clients.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String phone = (String) jsonObject.get("Phone Number");
        System.out.println(phone);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Heatmap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: can you upload the JSON object please?

Comment: @user3762083 The error message says that the file contains a JSON array, but your code expects the file to contain a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception thrown, i think it could be that clients.json it's an array, so you should have something like this:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\clients.json"));
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
JSONObject client= (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("0");
String phone = (String) client.get("Phone Number");
System.out.println(phone);
```

Hope it helps !